# Is SQL 'clever enough' to optimise out a NULL check in a simple where?

Tags: sql, select, null, where-clause, sql-server-2014

Title can be a bit confusing, admittedly, so I'll start with an example.

I have a table with a massive amount of data in. I'm passing in a date to a stored procedure which will be used as part of a `where` on a pretty standard `select`:

```
@MinDate DATETIME

SELECT *
FROM   MyTable
WHERE  (@MinDate IS NULL OR DatePublished >= @MinDate)
```

This works fine, but is the database evaluating `@MinDate` for every single record? i.e. does it hit the `where` and have to check for a `null` or not every time? If so, would it be quicker to refactor it to:

```
@MinDate DATETIME

IF(@MinDate IS NULL)
   SELECT *
   FROM   MyTable
ELSE
   SELECT *
   FROM   MyTable
   WHERE  DatePublished >= @MinDate
```

EDIT: Please ignore some small syntax errors, I've taken this out of context for the sake of simplicity. The premise of what I'm asking is still clear.

Comment: Just check execution plan for first with MinDate provided and NULL. Anyway your question is rather about **`short-circuit evaluation`**

Comment: The answer depends on the dbms used. Tag the one you are using.

Comment: There is a potential performance problem here. I use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` for such queries. Read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog for details and other approaches to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does include nulls in its index and statistics but whether it is useful or not depends on the selectivity of the column. If you have lots of null values then it's likely more efficient to do a scan than seek just because you'll end up reading the same or more pages anyway.

So yes, SQL Server will try to generate an efficient plan for your query but what it actually ends up doing depends on the data and available index (it can also auto-build statistics if enabled). Pretty easy to verify by looking at the query plan.

Btw, your second query returns different results from the first one (valid TSQL syntax not withstanding).

Answer (score -1):

SQL is neither clever or thumb. It is the query optimizer of your DBMS. Generally speaking the optimizers are pretty smart, otherwise SQL would be almost useless.
The optimizers try hard to avoid looking at every row.

So expect that your DBMS optimize it. Even if not, I would expect that this not the performance bottleneck of your app. You just should make sure you have an index on `DatePublished`.

If you want to be sure, look up the documentation of your DBMS how to check the "execution plan" or how to log when the DBMS does a full table scans.